# Why does my XMLHttpRequest not allow XSS?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, client, xss

I am writing a simple app to pull down news stories from the bbc rss feed at http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml.

It needs to run entirely on the client and not make use of jQuery, so JSONP is not a possible solution.  I have been testing with IE on localhost and clicking the "Allow Content" button that pops up as it detects a cross site request.  Chrome and Firefox aren't so simple to get them to allow this, and I now want to test on those browsers to see if my app works on them.

So far .....
I have tried changing my Javascript to use a CORS request like so ...

```js
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {

    // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
    // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);

  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {

    // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
    // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);

  } else {

    // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
    xhr = null;

  }
  return xhr;
}
```

```js
var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', feedURL);
 xhr.withCredentials = true;
 if (!xhr) {
   throw new Error('CORS not supported');
 }
 xhr.onload = function() {
     if (xhr.status === 200) {
      var xmlDoc;
   if (window.DOMParser){
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xhr.responseText,"text/xml");
   }
   else{ // Internet Explorer
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async=false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(xhr.responseText); 
   }

   //do some stuff
     }
     else {
         alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
     }
 };
 xhr.send();
```

I have also uploaded it to my web server and hosted it with IIS 6.  I added a web config, with these settings.

```html
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="rss.html" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I found an article about setting Handler Mappings in IIS.  Suggesting to set the OPTIONSVerbHandler to ISAPI ... however I don't have that setting.

Anyone that can shed some light on this. I would greatly appreciate it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research.  It seemed that the easiest solution was to create my own proxy.

- Convert the static site into a blank ASP.Net Web Application
- Create a generic handler in the project that contacts the bbc feed from the server
- Call that handler from the client side JS

Here is my handler for anyone interested

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;

namespace Feed
{
    /// 
    /// Summary description for rss
    /// 
    public class rss : IHttpHandler
    {

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string locationsRequest = CreateRequest();
        context.Response.Write(locationsRequest);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static string CreateRequest()
    {
        return XmlHttpRequest("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml", "");
    }

    public static string XmlHttpRequest(string urlString, string xmlContent)
    {
        string response = null;
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = null;//Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebRequest class.
        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = null;//Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebResponse class

        //Creates an HttpWebRequest for the specified URL.
        httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlString);

        try
        {
            byte[] bytes;
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlContent);
            //Set HttpWebRequest properties
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";

            using (Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                //Writes a sequence of bytes to the current stream 
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                requestStream.Close();//Close stream
            }

            //Sends the HttpWebRequest, and waits for a response.
            httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            if (httpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //Get response stream into StreamReader
                using (Stream responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            httpWebResponse.Close();//Close HttpWebResponse
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {   //TODO: Add custom exception handling
            throw new Exception(we.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception(ex.Message); }
        finally
        {
            httpWebResponse.Close();
            //Release objects
            httpWebResponse = null;
            httpWebRequest = null;
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

}